# "fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed" error

Tags: installation, usb, grub2

I am running a 64bit laptop and i am trying to install ubuntu 11.04 from both a usb and cd.  However, when I click either install from disk or try ubuntu I get to a black screen with this: fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

acpi=off this solve the booting problem

To use this option, using any editor, open /etc/default/grub

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

**Change the line – `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”` to**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
```

And then update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```