# "FIXING RECURSIVE FAULT BUT REBOOT IS NEEDED!" During installation

Tags: 11.04, 64-bit, installation

I'm a big fan of Ubuntu. I've installed it on every computer I had. But they were always 32-bit computers. And I've never had an experience with 64-bit computers.

I've made a live USB and CD but with both I get the same error:

`FIXING RECURSIVE FAULT BUT REBOOT IS NEEDED!`

Hardware Specification:

- Toshiba SDatellite L645D.
- AMD Turion II P540 Dual-Core Processor.
- 2.40 GHz.
- 4.00 of RAM.

Comment: similar question here reported your error - does the answer help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/38217/fixing-recursive-fault-but-reboot-is-needed-error

Comment: If you attempt to install the 32bit version, do you have the same issue?

Comment: could you explain how you get to the error message? How far in the installation did you get?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug according to what I've read on Launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/775950

The very last comment dated 16.06.2011 from Felix Griewald claims to have sorted the problem.

> Felix Griewald wrote on 2011-06-16:
>
> I confirm that the bug appears to be fixed in Linux Kernel 2.6.39
>
> I installed the Ubuntu mainline kernel
>   v2.6.39-oneiric and you also need
>   fgrlx 2:8.850 (you can use the
>   Ubuntu-X ppa).
>
> Tested on Lenovo Y560 Tested about 3
>   reboots without AC plugged in - it
>   seams to work.

Comment: thanks for the reply but thats not really helping me. I don't have ubuntu installed. I can't even load the live cd because I get that error.

Comment: Sorry Carlos, I misunderstood.  Did you burn the .ISO at the slowest speed possible?, doing that ensures that the image quality is perfect.